# Comparing vote recounts to official recount

Tags: inference

A vote is taken between two candidates and the official count reports one candidate wins.
The losing candidate asks for a recount. Three recounts are performed. The winning candidate is still winning in the first two recounts but the losing candidate is the winner in the third recount. The recounts are of all the votes (ballots).

How should one determine which count among the four should be the final official count?

Is there a statistical weigh to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! "How does one statistically determine which recount is valid?" One does not. IANAL: from a legal perspective the final recount is the valid one. From a statistical perspective, can you help me understand why you don't consider this to be a proportion problem?

Comment: Reply to John Madden.